Access to jandex index in AsyncAPIFilter
I'm using a implementation of AsyncAPIFilter to customize AsyncAPI spec. I declared a filter in properties. How to get an access to Jandex index in the filter? Something like in Open API
@OpenApiFilter( OpenApiFilter.RunStage.BOTH )
public class MyOpenApiCustomizer implements OASFilter
{
    private final IndexView index;

    public MyOpenApiCustomizer ( IndexView index )
    {
        this.index = index;
    }
}

?

Are you creating a quarkus extension or this in your app ? The OpenAPI works because the extension allows this.

No, I'm trying to us existing extension for Async API. https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkiverse.asyncapi/quarkus-asyncapi/ There is a posibility of implementing AsyncApiFilter which is needed to declara in properties. But then I don't know how to get Jandex index

That extension will need to enable that. You can look at the OpenAPI code to see how it's done and do a PR to add that feature to the AsyncAPI.
